# why I have to use "&" in &ip_reply->saddr

Tags: c, linux, ip

I use a program to extract source address from received packet. but I don't understand the use of & operator in the following code:

==> function to convert address

```
struct in_addr {
        unsigned long int s_addr; }

char *inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in);
```

==> receive packet

```
recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct icmphdr), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&connection, &addrlen)) == -1)
```

===> display source address

```
struct iphdr* ip_reply;

/*code */

ip_reply   = (struct iphdr*) buffer;

/*code */

printf("RCV ip->daddr = %s \n",inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)&ip_reply->saddr)));
```

Why do I have to use `&` in `&ip_reply->saddr`?

Comment: If you don't know how/when/why to use the addressof operator, then practically you have no idea about memory management. You should learn the basics of C first, only then should you make complex programs (such as TCP/IP communication).

Comment: Or you could learn TCP/IP by coding in a higher level language providing interface to Unix syscalls, e.g. in [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/) (using its [Unix](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/libref/Unix.html) module). This would relief you from low level manual management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the & operator (address of), because inet_ntoa require address of the variable that is ip_reply->saddr which is basically your source ip addr. You cannot pass this as the value, but as the address. You should learn a few pointers and data structures, before going to tcp/ip sockets programming.

Answer (score 3):

It's the address-of operator. It takes the operand and returns the address of the operand, in other words it returns a pointer to the operand.

In this case the code is making a pointer to `ip_reply->saddr`, typecasts it to a pointer to `struct in_addr`, and then dereferences the pointer. It's a way of casting arbitrary data from one type to another.

Comment: no !! inet_ntoa dont needs a pointer as argument => see function

Comment: @stack_A You're right. I must still be sleeping. Updated my answer.